# 'labels %s not contained in axis' % labels[mask])

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code which I use to drop columns with names:

('CreatedOn_Hour','CreatedOn_Minute','CreatedOn_Second','AvailableTo_Hour','AvailableTo_Minute','AvailableTo_Second','TransDate_Hour','TransDate_Minute','TransDate_Second'), but I can't. It shows the following error:

> KeyError: "labels ['CreatedOn_Second' 'AvailableTo_Second' 'TransDate_Hour'\n 'TransDate_Minute' 'TransDate_Second'] not contained in axis""

and my code is:

`dataset.drop(['CreatedOn_Hour','CreatedOn_Minute','CreatedOn_Second',
'AvailableTo_Hour','AvailableTo_Minute','AvailableTo_Second','TransDate_Hour',
'TransDate_Minute','TransDate_Second'], axis=1, inplace=True)`

Edit:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn import preprocessing 
dataset = pd.read_csv('latestdata1 - Copy.csv')
dataset.drop(['CreatedOn_Hour','CreatedOn_Minute','CreatedOn_Second','AvailableTo_Hour','AvailableTo_Minute','AvailableTo_Second','TransDate_Hour','TransDate_Minute','TransDate_Second'], axis=1, inplace=True) #le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
#df1=pd.DataFrame[Name] = le.fit_transform(df1[Name].astype(str)) #df[Name]=df[Name].astype('Name') #dataset = dataset.apply(le.fit_transform) X=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
```

Comment: Can you post the columns of your data frame `df`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not specify the columns when importing from text. If you provide your code where you generate the dataset, we could help more.

**Edit** I think what you are missing is the header=0 when reading from csv file. So it should look like this:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('latestdata1 - Copy.csv', header=0)
```

This option chooses the 0th row of csv file to be the column names. I hope this helps.

Comment: import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
dataset = pd.read_csv('latestdata1 - Copy.csv')

dataset.drop(['CreatedOn_Hour','CreatedOn_Minute','CreatedOn_Second','AvailableTo_Hour','AvailableTo_Minute','AvailableTo_Second','TransDate_Hour','TransDate_Minute','TransDate_Second'], axis=1, inplace=True)

#le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
#df1=pd.DataFrame[Name] = le.fit_transform(df1[Name].astype(str))
#df[Name]=df[Name].astype('Name')
#dataset = dataset.apply(le.fit_transform)
X=dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values

Comment: Can you also include your csv file?